# Getting error on an android app only for api level 23 ,on api 24 it is working fine

Tags: android, firebase

Here is the error:

--------- beginning of crash, here, please have a look at xml code,

Getting error on an android app only for api level 23 ,on api 24 is its working fine, please help I am new in android and its very painfull to have error in specific apis,
**App crashed on api level 23 and 24 is working fine**

```
>E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.a2zdaddy.dailynews, PID: 12188
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.a2zdaddy.dailynews/com.a2zdaddy.dailynews.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class Button
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class Button
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                      at com.a2zdaddy.dailynews.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:87)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class Button
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                      at com.a2zdaddy.dailynews.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:87) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.a2zdaddy.dailynews:dr
```

xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="6"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.a2zdaddy.dailynews.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4.2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_firebase_lockup"
            android:src="@mipmap/logo4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Register and Start Posting"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTitleText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            style="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTextDetail"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="You are not logged in !" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detail"
                style="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTextDetail"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="Veriication Sucessfull" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_below="@+id/detail"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.8"
        android:background="#ddaf0f75"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/phone_auth_fields"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2.0">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/field_phone_number"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_phone_number"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyLightEditText"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:inputType="phone"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/field_verification_code"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_verification_code"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyLightEditText"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:inputType="number"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3.0">

                <Button
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton"

                    android:id="@+id/button_start_verification"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_priority_high_black_24dp"
                    android:text="@string/start_phone_auth"/>

                <Button
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton"
                    android:id="@+id/button_verify_phone"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="@string/verify_phone_auth"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_verified_user_black_24dp"/>

                <Button
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton"
                    android:id="@+id/button_resend"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="@string/resend_phone_auth"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_settings_backup_restore_black_24dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/signed_in_buttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:weightSum="1.0">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="Sign Out"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


<!-- Activity with no Title -->
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyNoTitleActivity" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<!-- Dark Buttons -->
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<!-- Light EditTexts -->
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyLightEditText" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyTextDetail" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:fadeScrollbars">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">5</item>
    <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.FirebaseIcon" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/icon_top_margin</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/icon_bottom_margin</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyTitleText" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">36sp</item>
</style>
```

build-gradle
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.a2zdaddy.dailynews"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'


    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'



    compile 'com.lsjwzh:materialloadingprogressbar:0.5.8-RELEASE'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}














apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you show us the layout of your `res` folder? Do you have any version-specific resource filters e.g. `res/layout-v24`? And do you also get this crash on API 22 and below?

Comment: I do not have any version specific layout i think,please look at the xml

Comment: post style's xml file of ur button

Comment: please have a look , styles xml is added

Comment: most probably  you are using theme for button that is not supported by api level 23..so for cross checking remove theme from your button and re run your code with normal button on api level 23 ans check if that works or not

Comment: no , its not working.. In my another app I had used the same xml code and its running fine on api 23 , but for this app its not running,giving error on activty_main layout file

Comment: [FirebaseUI docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies) indicate you should be using `firebase-ui-database:2.3.0` with Firebase SDK 11.0.4.